# Gesture Recognizer not triggered iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have an image view on scroll view. I added more than one sub views on image view.

> ->UIScrollView
>
> -->UIImageView
>
> --->UIViews

I want to add gesture recognizer to subviews. But It doesn't work. Where is my mistake? function *handleTap()* not triggered.

```
 func addSubViewOnImageView(mPoint:CGPoint, mSize: CGSize){
    let rect = CGRect(origin: mPoint, size: mSize)
    let sView = UIView(frame: rect)
    sView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,  action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    tap.delegate = self
    sView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    imageView.addSubview(sView)
  }

 @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tapped any sub view")
  }
```

Comment: check isUserInteractionEnabled of imageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This property is inherited from the UIView parent class. This class changes the default value of this property to NO.

enable the user interaction for your imageview, by default its false , for more info you get the info from [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621063-userinteractionenabled?language=objc)

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 2):

just check

```
yourImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

is there or not?

An Alternate if you don't want to do 
`yourImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Just make your `UIView class a subclass of UIControl from storyboard` refer from screenshot.

it will act as an `UIButton` no need to write the code for adding an tap gesture`just add an action and like`normally we do for UIImageView`

[image]